# Python:What's wrong in my unit testing code?

Tags: python, testing

I have two files
"testable.py":

```
def joiner(x,y):
 return x+y
```

"test_testable.py":

```
import unittest
import testable

class TestTestable(unittest.TestCase):
 def setUp(self):
  self.seq = ['a','b','1']
  self.seq2 = ['b','c',1]

 def test_joiner(self):
  for each in self.seq:
   for eachy in self.seq2:
    self.assertRaises(TypeError,testable.joiner(each,eachy))

if __name__ == '__main__':
 unittest.main()
```

Now when I run the test I get:

```
ERROR: test_joiner (test_testable.TestTestable)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rajat/collective_knowledge/test_testable.py", line 16, in test_joiner
    self.assertRaises(TypeError,testable.joiner(each,eachy),(each,eachy))
  File "/home/rajat/collective_knowledge/testable.py", line 11, in joiner
    return x+y
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're miss using [`assertRaises`](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) it should be:

```
self.assertRaises(TypeError,testable.joiner, (each,eachy))
```

Or just use it as a context manager if you're using python2.7 and above or unittest2:

```
with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
     testable.joiner(each,eachy)
```

**EDIT :**

You should also replace `self.seq2 = [1,2,3]` for example.

Comment: FAIL: test_joiner (test_testable.TestTestable)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rajat/collective_knowledge/test_testable.py", line 17, in test_joiner
    testable.joiner(each,eachy)
AssertionError: TypeError not raised

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)

Comment: That's because your testing data is wrong (at least from the test) b/c concatenating two strings is correct, the only one that will make your test succeed are the one with ``'*' + 1``, so i think you want to do: ``self.seq2 = [1,2,3]``

Comment: oh thanks,Also can you suggest me a nice guide to unit testing(esp. for django)?

Comment: IMHO the doc (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/) is a good reference.

Comment: @Rajat You should write separate tests for valid inputs (positive tests) and invalid inputs (negative).

Answer (score 0):

In

```
for each in self.seq:
    for eachy in self.seq2
```

each could be 'a' and eachy could be 1

You can't add 'a' and 1 so the test fails.

Comment: Yeah,That's what I am testing.It should raise TypeError and my test code should tell that it's raised